# Why Are Some R Packages So Hard to Install?

Tags: r

Most of the time when I want to install an R package, I use the following code in R:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

And this usually works.

However, sometimes the installation is not so straightforward. For example, this R package (https://github.com/Datactuariat/Rpostal) requires multiple confusing steps before being able to be installed - creating confusion and many possible places to make mistakes during the installation.

As per my naïve understanding of computers, each function that you use in R has source code.  For example, the source code of many R functions is available here : https://rdrr.io/

In the case of this R library that has been giving me problems, **why did the creators not make it so that the "install.packages()" command could have been used to directly install this package?** I tried looking on this github page to find the source code for all the functions that are used in this package, but I could not find them. **Why can't I just copy the source code/definitions for all the functions in this library, paste them into R Studio and thereby effectively recreate this library in my local R session and avoid the headache of going through this convoluted installation process?**

**Can someone please comment on this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Rpostal is just a wrapper around libpostal, all the functions are written and accessed by calling C. Libpostal is the one that requires a c libraries to be installed and that uses programs like MinGW or others to install correctly, and not Rtools. Hence it is not on cran. catboost is another package on github that requires other tools to install correctly for use in R. But then the same goes for having these tools running in correctly in python. Another package using libpostal is https://github.com/ironholds/poster, but with the same caveats that libpostal needs to be installed beforehand.

Comment: @ phiver: thank you so much for your reply! I wish someone would just write the R code for these packages so they could be hosted on CRAN

Comment: It's not so much the code as the dependencies to C that are the issue. CRAN doesn't accept  / tends not to like those. This in part because the C libraries needed are not on their deployment and test servers so packages like this can't be tested. If they would host these and there are issues with it, people would complain about this.

Comment: In theory someone could rewrite the underlying C code into C++ and use rcpp to get it on cran, but that is a lot of work that nobody is going to pay for. So.....

Comment: Thank you for your insights ... this problem can't be fixed by hosting this package on github?